# How to run an app after running an xcode clean and clean build folder where the app now crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I'm trying to run my app after running an Xcode clean and clean build folder and I'm now getting this error and a crash:

fyi: there was a file called `DetailViewController` that I deleted because I didn't need it anymore. It's only after running a clean and clean build folder that this crash has been occurring.

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/4E0DB510-4107-4F8D-A08C-ECFDDB1DB506/1000 appname.app> (loaded)' with name 'DetailViewController'
```

I tried deleting the contents of /Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/ to remove the apps on the simulator.

I also reset the Simulator. Closed and re-ran the program but still getting that error.

thanks for any help

Comment: Is 'DetailViewController' registered to the target you are trying to build?  It will show up under 'Copy Bundle Resources' in the project settings navigation panel, when selecting the target you are building.

Comment: DetailViewController shouldn't exist anymore. Is there somewhere to check if a reference to it is still hanging around?  It's only after running a clean and clean build folder that this crash has been occurring.

Comment: Well then do the converse, check to see that this file has been unregistered from all targets.  Sorry, read your post slightly wrong.  My comment edits should explain how to be sure it isn't registered to the given target.  Here's a link that will help as well: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1649/_index.html

Comment: Either check the main storyboard Views, there could be some view that is using the DetailviewContoller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, certain files get cached even with 'Clean Build Folder', especially for simulator. Files (especially derived nibs and images) can be left that have been deleted in the project.

- Command-Option-Shift-K to clean out the build folder.
- Quit Xcode and clean out ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData manually.
- In the simulator, choose iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings.

Now if it fails, it is because your code was only working *because* of over-cached build files. If this is the case, check where your rootViewController is pointing.